# What is the difference between these two ajax scripts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm running into difficulty with the JSON cross domain policy issue. After a little experimentation I was able to get this code working, but I came across a situation where I had two pieces of code which seem like they should be exactly the same, but only one works.

The JSON I am accessing is here

> http://www.aph.com/files/partners/aphnonstopproducts/json/aphnonstopproductsjson.json

This file appears to be straightforward JSONP: it doesn't take any parameters, and JSON padded with a function call called jsonCallBack. It appears to be valid JSON.

Here's the first set of code which I tried to use to grab this JSON data:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.aph.com/files/partners/aphnonstopproducts/json/aphnonstopproductsjson.json?callback=jsonCallback", function (data) {
                //This will not alert
                alert(data.APHNonStopProducts.Carpark[0].Airport.airportcode);            
            });
```

My understanding was that you could replace the `callback=?` with the name of the function wrapper in order to have that data passed to the anonymous function. This code shows the following error in Chrome Dev tools:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.aph.com/files/partners/aphnonstopproducts/json/aphnonstopproductsjson.json?callback=jsonCallback.
>   Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

It's worth noting that if leave the URL as `aphnonstopproductsjson.json?callback=?` and have a named function present in my code then the data is retrieved properly and the named function called (although the anonymous one still isn't)

Here's the second code, which works:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.aph.com/files/partners/aphnonstopproducts/json/aphnonstopproductsjson.json?callback=?",
       dataType: 'json',
       jsonp : "callback",
       jsonpCallback: "jsonCallback",
       success: function(data) {
           //This alert will fire
           alert(data.APHNonStopProducts.Carpark[0].Airport.airportcode);
       }
   });
});​
```

In this call, I'm specifying that the parameter name should be callback, and the function name should be jsonCallback. So in essence, isn't that the same as the first code? If so, why does the first code fail?

See both pieces of code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3EXca/ (You should receive an alert which says "ABZ")

Comment: Did you test in all browsers? I think this errors comes from FireFox

Comment: That is *not* valid JSONP.  JSONP allows specifying the callback name.

Comment: @bobek, I'm primarily testing in Chrome, but I do also receive an error in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the server doesn't support JSONP properly.  Without a callback parameter, there should not be a callback.  Instead, it already has a jsonCallback.  There may be a way to override that, but I can't guess the parameter.

For `$.getJSON` to work with JSONP, the server has to support JSONP with some callback parameter name.

The second works because you're forcing jQuery to use the function name `jsonCallback`.  The:

```
jsonp: 'callback'
```

doesn't matter since it always wraps with `jsonCallback` anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matthew. However I'm still confused between the difference between the pieces of code. Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: The first does not work because jQuery does not know to use `jsonCallback` as the function name.

Comment: @AndyF, in fact, as you can tell from the error, it doesn't even know to use a `script` tag (JSONP).